# jQuery plugin bind to dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Following sample plugin does not work on dynamically created element.

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MSkm6/)

```
$.fn.getData = function() {
    return this.click(function() {
        alert($(this).data("aloc"));    
    }); 
};

$("a").getData();
```

I can do it using `jQuery.livequery` plugin as

```
$("a").livequery(function() {
    $(this).getData();
});
```

But want to do this facility without `livequery` in my plugin

Answer (score 2):

Well for delegated events you need to use `.on()` as per jQuery 1.7 and after . here you go i have modified your code  as below and its working as you intend to.

**Jquery Code:**

```
//plugin
$.fn.getData = function () {
   return $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
      alert($(this).data("aloc"));
   });
};
```

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/MSkm6/9/

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are not setting an event listener to the dynamically created element, and you know what happens when you don't! nothing happens and it wont get triggered, so try changing your plugin code a bit:

```
$.fn.getData = function() {
    var tagName=$(this).prop("tagName"); //if you wanna get the element by tagname
    var elemID='#'+$(this).attr("id"); //if you wanna get the element by id
    var elemClass='.'+$(this).attr("class"); //if you wanna get the element by class
    return $(document).bind('click','put tagName or elemID or elemClass based on your needs here',function() {
        alert($(this).data("aloc"));    
    }); 
};

$("a").getData();
```

now it gives you the result you want.

UPDATE: or you can simply use:

```
$.fn.getData = function() {
    return $(this).bind('click',function() {
        alert($(this).data("aloc"));    
    }); 
};

$("a").getData();
```

Comment: Clicking anywhere in document I got alert message

Comment: sorry my bad, check the answer again

Comment: I have checked your UPDATE part, it does not work on new items

Comment: how about the first part? I changed that too

Comment: If you like first part why not use `$(document).bind('click',this.selector,function(){ ... });`

Comment: because you can not set an object in the selector part, just selectors

Comment: No, of course you can use this line given in comment

Comment: `this.id` returns "someID" it's missing the "#", so it wont do the desired functionality, but maybe you're right, I haven't tried that, but in theory as far as I know, it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can add .getData() after define a tag. It will work.

```
//create new element
$("#NewElement").click(function(){
    var n = $('a').length+1;
    $("<a href='#' data-aloc='a"+n+"'>New Test "+n+"</a><br />").getData().insertBefore($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsXHv/)

```
$.fn.getData = function() {
    return $(document).on('click',this.selector,function() {
        alert($(this).data("aloc"));    
    }); 
};
$("a").getData();
```